# Use of macros in C

Tags: c, c-strings

I am trying to produce an output as double quoted input . For e.g if the argument that is passed in str() is some **name** then the output should be **"name"** which is not happening in below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define str(s) #s
#define newline printf("\n")

int main()

{

  printf("Your double quoted code is : %s ",str(GHOST));
  newline;
}
```

> Output : GHOST

Comment: This is almost the most unidiomatic C code I've ever seen. (Excluding obfuscation / code-golf contests)

Comment: Please, don't write code like this. I suggest against the use of macro definitions until you understand the language itself. Just a piece of advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is happening is that the quotes *are* being added, but they are consumed as part of the syntax of the language. Because, you need to pass a *string* like `"GHOST"` to `printf`, not just an identifier.

If you want quotes to appear when you run the program, I would make it

```
printf("Your double quoted code is : \"%s\" ",str(GHOST));
```

instead. The escaped quotes in the format string will appear in the output.

Answer (score 5):

You should edit your format to `\"%s\"`

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
printf("Your double quoted code is : \"%s\"",str(GHOST));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the stringify operator to a string:

```
#define xstr(x) #x
#define str(x) xstr(x)
#define quote(x) str(str(x))

int main() {
  printf("Your double quoted code is : %s ",quote(GHOST));
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```

However, the side effect of using `xstr` to rescan the argument to `str` -- which is necessary for the inner `str(GHOST)` to be expanded is that if `GHOST` is itself a macro definition, it will be expanded, unlike the `GHOST` in the snippet of code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the double-quote characters in your output, then either change your format string to

```
printf("Your double quoted code is : \"%s\" ",str(GHOST));
```

or change your macro to

```
#define str(s) "\"" #s "\""
```

I would advise not using macros in this way, but you asked the question.